Mux uploading the same video
Does anyone have an idea on how to reset mux uploader after success?
I'm trying to implement a system that allows you upload a video and get the playback id on success before saving the playback id in a database.
<MuxUploader id="mux-uploader" noDrop endpoint={upload.url}
   onSuccess={async () => {
      const playback = await getPlaybackInfo(upload.id)

      sectionFormik.setFieldValue("video", playback)
   }}
/>

I've tried picking up bits from the mux + next example project but what keeps happening is that the uploader gets back the same playback id of a previous upload on success despite them being different videos

I think there's a response to your question over on Reddit, but for anyone else looking at this: I think what's happening here is that you might be using the same direct upload details for multiple uploads. It's a 1:1 mapping between a direct upload and an asset, so you need to create a direct upload for each new video you're uploading.
